# Full Name from email address

Tags: email

Is it possible to find the Full Name of a person from the email address?

If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Not with any degree of accuracy, if that's what you're going for.

Comment: This isn't a bad question.  It may show his ignorance in how email works -- but really doesn't merit down votes if he assumed the possibility that he could extract this information programatically.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no global mapping of email addresses to full names.

If you're working in an enterprise that maintains a directory service like LDAP or Active Directory then this service could be used to do what you want for people in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

Email them and ask them their name.  Failing that, I like Mr. Cooper's answer.  :)

Comment: +1 for the tongue in your cheek.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Stick the email into Google, Bing, Facebook, Linkedin, MySpace and see what comes up.